# How to verify a message?

Tags: authentication

I have a 192 bit data string and a 384 bit signature calculated with curve `ANSIp192r1` as well as the public key.

These readings originate from a SYM2 electricity meter and I would like to independently validate the authenticity.

What is the best way to verify the message using the public key?

Comment: Possible duplicati on of question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257185/how-does-a-public-key-verify-a-signature

Comment: Not so.  The question 18257185 is about how signatures and keys work.  This question is about the best tool to use.

Comment: Road map in absence of any suggestions now as follows:  get seccure; vector test; test with data using -b option.  (Steep learning curve...)